# Условия внутри конструкции switch

Tags: switch, javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? [Прочитал](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), что внутри switch можно поставить дополнительные условия и упростить\укоротить код, но что-то он отказывается выполнять условия и просто выдает то, что прописано в блоке default.

Собственно, простой код:

```
var dateInt = parseInt(getDaysLeft(dataUser[2]),10);
var result = "Unknown";

   switch(dateInt){

    case -2:
      result = "Yesterday";
    break;

    case -1:
      result = "To day";
    break;

    case dateInt>0 && dateInt<=8:
      result = getTextDay(dataUser[2]);
    break;

    default:
      result = "Default";
    break;

   }
```

На выходе выводит "Default", несмотря на то, что значения для условия совпадают.

Функция getDaysLeft выдает разницу между двумя датами в числовом эквиваленте.

Comment:     switch( true)

тогда можно было бы делать

    case( a==b  && c<d):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, конечно, можете использовать не только статические значения в case, то не стоит забывать, что сравнение все равно идет как dateInt === value. Можно использовать, конечно, небольшой трюк, чтобы все работало примерно по задуманному:

```
var dateInt = parseInt(getDaysLeft(dataUser[2]),10);
var result = "Unknown";

switch(dateInt){
    case -2:
      result = "Yesterday";
    break;

    case -1:
      result = "To day";
    break;

    case dateInt>0 && dateInt<=8 ? dateInt : true:
      result = getTextDay(dataUser[2]);
    break;

    default:
      result = "Default";
    break;

}
console.log(result)
```

P.S. Хочу заметить, что с точки зрения оформления кода это выглядит ужасно, может порождать ошибки и не приветствуется. Вы либо используете статические значения в case, либо используете if для условий.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(dateInt){

    case -2:
      result = "Yesterday";
    break;

    case -1:
      result = "To day";
    break;

    default:
      result = dateInt>0 && dateInt<=8 ? getTextDay(dataUser[2]) : "Default";
    break;

   }
```

Вариант 2:

```
switch(dateInt){
  case -2:
    result = "Yesterday";
  break;

  case -1:
    result = "To day";
  break;

  case dateInt>0:
  case dateInt<=8:
    result = getTextDay(dataUser[2]);
  break;

  default:
    result = "Default";
  break;
}
```

Comment: По второму варианту для потомков: условия `case` срабатывают как `ИЛИ`. Т.е. получаем `dateInt > 0` ИЛИ `dateInt <= 8` что верно всегда. Т.е. в данном случае эти два case\`а равносильны `default` (если надо сравнивать `boolean`, а не числа). В php такого ограничения нет, поэтому эта ветка сработает всегда